# Ubuntu 18.04 LTS network connections stop working (r8812au)

Tags: networking, drivers, 18.04, network-manager, internet

I have a clean Ubuntu 18.04 machine that I set up recently. When I first installed, there was no Wi-Fi driver. No problem, I connected my iPhone with a USB cable and was able to use that as an internet connection. I then went to Additional Drivers and installed the 3rd party driver (r8812au). Everything worked flawlessly.

Now, a few days later, seemingly for no reason at all, the internet connection has stopped working. What's worse, if I connect my iPhone (hotspot configured correctly) that doesn't work either for some reason!

How can I diagnose what's going on? net-tools (i.e. ifconfig) are not installed, and those are what I'm familiar with. How do I figure out what's going on?

If I run `sudo lshw -c network` I get:

```
*-network

description: Ethernet interface
physical id: 1
bus info: usb@1:13
logical name: eth0
serial: 06:4b:...
capabilities: ethernet physical
configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iphet link=no multicast=yes
```

`dmesg` shows all the normal stuff but finishes with "link is not ready".

I've tried it on another Ubuntu install and it works as expected there...

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean Ubuntu Core 18? or Ubuntu 18.04 LTS?  The primary Ubuntu releases are *yy.mm* in format, except for specialist releases which do you *yy* (Ubuntu Core 18 intended for IoT appliances).  Sure we can guess what you probably mean - but its better for all if we don't have to assume (*the mother of all f...*)

Comment: Good point, I've edited to specify 18.04 LTS.

Comment: I'm confused. Your lshw shows what appears to be a USB Ethernet adapter, but nothing wireless. What driver did you install? How does a phone USB connection give you Internet access. More details please.

Comment: By default Ubuntu comes with a driver that allows tethering to a phone's internet connection via USB. As I say it worked a few days ago (and now on other computers).

As for the wi-fi adapter: I too am confused, but I am guessing that some apt update broke that driver. In any case, if I can get the USB tethering to work, I'm sure I'll be able to fix the other issues, so that's my main question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a proper answer to my question, but I will put it here just in case it can help someone else.

I resolved the problem by doing the following:

- Go into **Driver Manager** (i.e. 3rd party drivers)
- Uncheck "Using dkms source for the r8812au network driver from rtl8812au-dkms"
- Click Apply
- Reboot
- Go into **Driver Manager** again
- Re-Check "Using dkms source for the r8812au network driver from rtl8812au-dkms"
- Click Apply
- Reboot

No idea why, but I needed to disable the driver and then re-enable it, as above, to get the Wi-Fi to woit to work again... I assume that the problem was tickled by some Ubuntu apt update, because the system is in a very clean state.